# Allow Facebook to access my site so that it can read OpenGraph meta tags

Tags: facebook, apache, .htaccess, facebook-opengraph

I am developing a new website for our company, so I have put the site on to the internet, but restricted access through .htaccess to certain IP addresses.

However, part of the new site is a 'Share on Facebook' button, so I need to test that, but Facebook is unable to connect to my site, and this is not grabbing the OpenGraph titles, descriptions, images, etc.

I've added `allow from facebook.com` to .htaccess, but this doesn't work, and the [Facebook linter](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://dev.dynedrewett.com/staff-profile/morgan-morgan/) reports a 403 when trying to connect. Temporaraly removing the access restrictions to the site allows the Facebook linter to connect.

Here is my full .htaccess file (minus real IP addresses) -

```
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php?error=404

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress

# Only allow access to the site from the IP's listed below
#order deny,allow
allow from 1.2.3.1 # sh_adsl
allow from 1.2.3.2 #sh_lease_lines
allow from 1.3.1.1 # sh
allow from 1.2.2.1 # sm
allow from 1.2.3.1 # wi
allow from 1.2.4.1 # fr
allow from 4.3.2.1 # dgard -  home local range
allow from facebook.com # to allow the Facebook sharing
#allow from all
deny from all

# Block access to wp-config.php
<Files wp-config.php>
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
</Files>

# Deny directory browsing
Options All -Indexes

# Prevent access to any file that begins with '.hta' (i.e. protect this file!)
<Files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
    order allow,deny
    deny from all
    satisfy all
</Files>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

List of FB crawlers IPs: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/ApplicationSecurity/#facebook_scraper

Add them to your `.htaccess` and you should be good to go.